# Error in key tool: java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish, keytool

I've been for several days trying to effectively implement HTTPS in a Glassfish server I work with, but it's just becoming impossible.

I'm trying to generate a key, and then generate a CSR to add it to my GlassFish server, and have a signed certificate to my HTTPS (now I have an untrusted certificate).

I enter in my Java folder, and run this command:

```
keytool -genkey -keystore keystore1.jks -alias newkey -storepass changeit -keypass changeit
```

It always retrieves the error you see in the title, saying that it cannot find the specified route. I tried many other routes:

C:\keystore1.jks
.\keystore1.jks
..\keystore1.jks

... yet nothing works. It just keeps retrieving the same error, so I can't do anything.

What can I do?

Comment: So are you trying to update the keystore for Glassfish?  Or the JRE?  Or what ...

Comment: I'm trying to generate a key, and then generate a CSR to add it to my GlassFish server, and have a signed certificate to my HTTPS (now I have an untrusted certificate).

Comment: So ... which keystore are you trying to update?

Comment: I'm trying to create a new one, since there's some problem with the default glassfish keystore (I can't access it). It gives the a "wrong password" error.

Comment: Are you sure that you have write access in those directories (".", "..", "C:\")?  Try changing to your home directory or the temporary directory and writing the keystore file there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is there is no access for write in your Java directory.

When I issued your command in my home directory - file was generated, after switching to Java bin dir (where keytool is located) I got FileNotFoundException.

Comment: So I should give write permissions to some account in order to be able to do this?

Comment: First variant: you can add keytool to your path variable (if it is not already there), then you can run keytool in some folder where you have permission to write. Second variant: call keytool by full path like /your/java/home/bin/keytool -genkey .... Third variant: set output file path to place where you can write like: keytool -genkey -keystore /your/home/dir/keystore1.jks [skipped]